# show that $2 \ln(x)-x^2+2=0$ has exactly two solutions in interval $(0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

I wrote $f(x)=2 \ln(x)-x^2+2=0$ and have shown that it has a solution in $[1,e]$ interval denoted as $c_1$ and another one in $[1/e,1]$, interval denoted as $c_2$ with the help of intermediate theorem, but what I couldn't prove is that there is no other solution than $c_1$ and $c_2$, so how can I prove that?

Answer (score 3):

You have $f'(x)=\frac2x-2x$, and therefore $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1]$ and strictly decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. So, it can only have *at most* on zero in each of these intervals. But you proved that it has one zero on each of them. So, $f$ has exactly two zeros.